# Reading data from xml file input by user Blazor web assembly

Tags: xml, file, blazor

So, I used `<input>` tag and input an xml file from the user. Now I want to read the content of the file. I want to be able to save the content as a JSON Object. This will be of the type IBrowserFile but I am not sure how can I use this to iterate over the file and fetch the data. If there is some other way to do so please let me know.
Sample html written is:

`<input type="file" onchange="@LoadFile" accept=".xml" />`

Please help me finding a solution for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a stream:

```
async Task LoadFile(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
   var stream = e.File.OpenReadStream();
   var doc = await XDocument.LoadAsync(stream, ...);
   // process your data
}
```

Note that Microsoft [does not recommend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly) this kind of in-memory operations, estimate your risks.

Comment: thank you for the response. Can you please help me with how it should be done?

Comment: The basic steps are provided here, not clear what more you need.